# entity framework no PK's on tables

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using VS2012 and creating a sample Entity Framework project that reads and writes to some tables that are used for import purposes.   and do not have PK's or FK's in them - just null/notnull on the columns.

Can/should EF be made to insert records on these tables without that cryptic error:

> *Unable to update the EntitySet because it has a DefiningQuery
>   and no  element exists in the
>    element to support the current
>   operation.*

Or should I be looking elsewhere for database I/O?

Thanks!
Corey.

Comment: I am not going to put it as an answer as there might be a hack somewhere. I don't think you can do that. I ran into the same problem before and had to just change my DBs.
I hope to get proven wrong here.

Comment: Without a primary key, the only possible uniqueness, is every column in the table, and that might not be unique anyway. Why use EF anyway for something like this? It's not really an entity and it doesn't fit the framework.